# AJAX live checking availability with submit button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

- test1.php

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#username').change(function(){
              var userName = $('#username').val();

              $.post("getUserName.php", {userName: userName}, function(data){
                  $("#userNameCheck").html(data);
              });
         }); 

         $('#submit').click(function(){
              //CODE HERE

         });
      });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <form action="" method="post" id="addform">
      Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="24" class="required" maxlength="22" />
      <div id="userNameCheck"></div>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="ADD user" />
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- getUserName.php

  ```
  <?php
  include("db.php");

  $userName = $_POST['userName'];
  $q = "select user_name from user where user_name = '".$userName."'";
  $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

  $num =  mysqli_num_rows($r);

  if($num)
  {
        echo '<div style="color:red">Username taken. Please type another new one.    
       </div>';
  }
  else
  {
        echo '<div style="color:green">You can use it.</div>';
  }
  ?>
  ```
- database (user table) 
  user_id          user_name 
   1                               ali    
   2                              abu
- From the above: 
  => type "**ali**" on textbox -> show "You can use it" messsage in green color.
  => type **ahmad** on textbox -> show "Username taken..." message in red color.
- My requirement is if the message is "You can use it", go to test2.php; if the message is "Username taken...", no submission on the form.
- My question is how do I control the "You can use it" or "Username taken" message when I click the submit button?

Comment: You have to use ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a click handler for the button, use the form submit event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#username').change(function () {
        var userName = $('#username').val();

        $.post("getUserName.php", {
            userName: userName
        }, function (data) {
            $("#userNameCheck").html(data);
        });
    });

    $('#addform').submit(function () {
        //if the text is `You can use it` allow the form submit else block it
        return $("#userNameCheck").html().trim() == 'You can use it';
    });
});
```

Also make sure that you do the same validation in `test2.php` because, the client side validation can be side stepped.