# AJAX live checking availability with submit button (part 2)

Tags: php, ajax

- Cont on [AJAX live checking availability with submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118629/ajax-live-checking-availability-with-submit-button/27118685#27118685)
- getUserName.php

  ```
  if($num)
  {
  echo '<img src="images/no.png" width="16" height="16" align="bottom" />';
  echo '<div style="color:red">Username was taken. Please type another new     
  one.</div>';
  }
  else
  {
  echo '<img src="images/yes.png" width="16" height="16" align="bottom" />';
  }
  ```
- Let's say I want to change the message into image.
  -> "Username taken" change to no.png
  -> "You can use it..." change to yes.png
- test1.php

  ```
  $('#addform').submit(function () {
  return $("#userNameCheck").html() == '<div><img src="images/yes.png" width="16" 
  height="16" align="bottom"></div>';
  });
  ```
- In part 1, I was use "You can use it" message go to test2.php; But now, I want to use the image(yes.png) instead of the message. However, it failed. How should I modify?

Answer (score 0):

If you have ID in the img do something like this

```
$("#my_image").attr("src","images/yes.png");
```

or

```
$("#userNameCheck img").attr("src","images/yes.png");
```

I would suggest not to inject HTML in the #usernamecheck div but have it as hidden or something. In that way you can tinker with it in CSS and show it when needed without going into the JS and seeing when and if you add it.