# AJAX live checking availability with submit button (part 3)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Cont on [AJAX live checking availability with submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118629/ajax-live-checking-availability-with-submit-button) && [AJAX live checking availability with submit button (part 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139761/ajax-live-checking-availability-with-submit-button-part-2)

**functions.php**

```
<?php
function AddUserForm()
{
?>
    <form id="adduser" name="adduser" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="30" maxlength="50" /><span id="usernameCheck"></span><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add User" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
    </form> 

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var frmvalidator = new Validator("adduser");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("username","req","Please fill up the username.");
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

**adduser.php**

```
<?php
include_once('functions.php');
?>

<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" src="formvalidator2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-themes-1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = false;

    $('#username').change(function(){
        var userName = $('#username').val();

         if(userName == "")
        {
             $("#usernameCheck").empty();
         }
         else
         {
             $.post("getUserName.php", {userName: userName}, function (data) 
             {
                 a = data; 
                 $("#usernameCheck").html(data);
             });
         }
    }); 

    //---[1]---
    $('#adduser').submit(function(){
        return a == 'username valid';             
    });
});
</script>   
</head>

<body>
<?php
AddUserForm();

//---[2]---
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'Add User'))
{
    echo $_POST['username'];
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**getUserName.php**

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'usertest') OR  die(mysqli_connect_error());

$userName = $_POST['userName'];
$q = "select user_name from user where user_name = '".$userName."'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

$num =  mysqli_num_rows($r);

if($num)
{
     echo 'username invalid';
}
else
{
     echo 'username valid';
}
?>
```

Here is my expected output:
[image]

Here is my requirements: 
(1) If user not fill in username 
     - Form validator will pop out the message "Please fill up the username message".

(2) If user fill in a user name not same with the database 
      - Show "Username valid" besides the username field.
      - Will display username after click the "Add User" button.

(3) If user fill in a user name same with the database 
      - Show "Username invalid" besides the username field.
      - Will not submit form after click the "Add User" button.

From my above code, I discovered that [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jFmV.png)] will submit the form.
On the other hand, [2] will also submit the form.
I don't want multiple submit form run in my web page.

Is there any way to fulfill my requirements in single submit form? 
Can someone assists me?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps to reach your desired functionality...

1. Listen for the focus event on the username

   `$("#username").on('focus', function() {
        // Insert Blur Listener Here
        // Insert Keyup Listener Here
    });`

   - Listen for the blur event on the username field

     - Make sure the value of the username field is not equal to ""

       - If it is equal to "", disable the submit button
       - If it is NOT equal to "", and the AJAX call reveals the username IS available... enable the submit button

         `$("#username").on('blur', function() {
            if( $(this).val() === "" ) {
                // If username value is empty SHOW ERROR
                $("#usernameCheck").html("Username Required!");
            } else {
                // Username field NOT empty, check username availability
                var userInput = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url : "getUserName.php",
                    method : "POST",
                    data : { userName : userInput },
                    success : function(response) {
                        if( response.indexOf("invalid") >= 0 ) {
                            $("#usernameCheck").html("Username Already In Use!");
                            // Username IS NOT available
                        } else {
                            // Username IS available
                            $("#usernameCheck").html("Username Available!");
                        }
                    },
                    error : function(error) {
                        // Handle PHP script errors here
                    }
                });
            }
         });`
   - Listen for the keyup event on the username field

     - Utilizing an AJAX call search your database for the userName value

       - `$("#username").on('keyup', function() {
            var userInput = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url : "getUserName.php",
                method : "POST",
                data : { userName : userInput },
                success : function(response) {
                    if( response.indexOf("invalid") >= 0 ) {
                        $("#usernameCheck").html("Username Already In Use!");
                        // Username IS NOT available
                    } else {
                        $("#usernameCheck").html("Username Available!");
                        // Username IS available
                    }
                },
                error : function(error) {
                    // Handle PHP script errors here
                }
            });
         });`
2. Listen for the submit event on the #addUser form, to perform a last second availability check

   - Prevent the default action
   - Run the AJAX call

     - On "valid", submit the form
     - On "invalid", show an error of some sort.
   - **THIS WOULD BE USED IN CASE THE USER RELOADS THE PAGE AND THE USERNAME INPUT HAS A VALUE BUT WAS NOT FOCUSED**
   - **THIS WILL ALSO CAPTURE ALL FORMS OF SUBMISSION (i.e. clicks, enter keypress, etc. )**

     `$("#addUser").on("submit", function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var userInput = $("#username").val();
         $.ajax({
             url : "getUserName.php",
             method : "POST",
             data : { userName : userInput },
             success : function(response) {
                 if( response.indexOf("invalid") >= 0 ) {
                     $("#usernameCheck").html("Username Already In Use!");
                 } else {
                     $("#addUser").submit();
                 }
             },
             error : function(error) {
                 // Handle PHP script errors here
             }
         });
     });`